# The css applied to an image is not working

Tags: html, css, image

Here is the code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee+Inline&display=swap');
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.stubimg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 36%;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  align-content: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #051721;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 319px;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-family: 'Bungee Inline', cursive;
}

nav a {
  position: relative;
  width: 33.333%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1A4645;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Bungee Inline', Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  transition: 0.2s ease color;
}

nav a:before,
nav a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.2s ease transform;
}

nav a:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}

nav a:after {
  top: 5px;
  left: 18px;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px
}

nav a:nth-child(1):before {
  background-color: #F8BD25;
}

nav a:nth-child(1):after {
  background-color: #cc7000;
}

nav a:nth-child(2):before {
  background-color: #F8BD25;
}

nav a:nth-child(2):after {
  background-color: #cc7000;
}

nav a:nth-child(3):before {
  background-color: #F8BD25;
}

nav a:nth-child(3):after {
  background-color: #cc7000;
}

#indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 12%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.2s ease left;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #286868;
}

nav a:hover:before,
nav a:hover:after {
  transform: scale(1);
}

nav a:nth-child(1):hover~#indicator {
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, #F8BD25, #cc7000);
}

nav a:nth-child(2):hover~#indicator {
  left: 45%;
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, #F8BD25, #cc7000);
}

nav a:nth-child(3):hover~#indicator {
  left: 78.5%;
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, #F8BD25, #cc7000);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <meta name="description" content="We are Stub.">
  <meta name="author" content="Stub">

  <meta property="og:title" content="Stub">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://stub.w3spaces.com/">
  <meta property="og:description" content="We are Stub">
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://stub.w3spaces.com/Stub_Tree.png">

  <link rel="icon" href="https://stub.w3spaces.com/Stub_Tree.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://stub.w3spaces.com/Stub_Tree.png">
  <!-- css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stub.w3spaces.com/main.css?bypass-cache=1625014765">
  <!-- fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Unica+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Varela+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumar+One+Outline&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Stub</title>

  <body>
    <img class "stubimg" src="https://stub.w3spaces.com/Stub_Tree.png" width="230px" height="230px">
    <nav>
      <a href="#">HOME</a>
      <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#">MUSIC</a>
      <div id="indicator"></div>
    </nav>
  </body>

</html>
```

I am trying to apply css 'top' 'left' and 'right' values to the image, so I can move it on the page. I have the class set up correctly, and I do not know why the css is not being applied to the image. The css for the image is just at the top, the rest of it is for the navbar animations.

Comment: the css is still not working

Answer (score 1):

put eqqual sign i front ot stubing

full HTML line

```
<img class="stubimg" src="https://stub.w3spaces.com/Stub_Tree.png" width="230px" height="230px">
```

Comment: OH LOL HAHA thank you so much I cannot believe I made such a silly typo. You are amazing, thank you for your answer! ha